# Мгновенное перенаправление в файл

Tags: python, linux

Есть python-скрипт:

```
from time import sleep

sleep(5)
print 'some_line1'
sleep(5)
print 'some_line2'
```

Выводит две строки с задержкой в 5 секунд.

Перенаправляем вывод в файл:

```
# python script.py > outfile.txt
```

Получаем в файле `outfile.txt` наши две строки, но только через 10 секунд, т.е. после полного выполнения скрипта, на протяжении всех 10 секунд файл был пустой.

Вопрос в том как получать эти данные в файл мгновенно, т.к. там может быть не две строки, а десятки тысяч, и ждать полного выполнения скрипта не хочется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это эффект изменения типа буферизации при перенаправлении стандартного вывода в файл. Нужно принудительно выводить буфер в нужный момент.

Для Python посмотрите, например, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print или погуглите (посмотрите соответствующую доку по нужной версии). Пример:

```
$ python -u script.py > outfile.txt
```

[`-u` опция командной строки](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) выключает буферы у стандартных потоков ввода/вывода.

Вообще, "ноги растут" из поведения `FILE *` (libc). Для более глубокого  понимания могу посоветовать почитать [man setbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setbuf).

Comment: Добавил после каждого print `sys.stdout.flush()`, работает прекрасно. Спасибо!